# Register domain with Google Apps remotely

Tags: google-apps

Is there any way to register for Google Apps remotely (i.e. with an API), if I already own the domain and can manage DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you are an ISP or large enough.  Given that you're asking here, instead of talking to your Google Enterprise rep, chances are this is a "no".

Comment: Upon further Googling, it turned out this is true. Anyway, I only wanted it for Google App Engine, but I decided to run my own DNS server and redirect all domains to my actual app domain.